# Python inheritance efficiency

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

im want to make class parent that have more then 2 subclasses and as you can see in the code example here, im want to use methods that behave different depend on child class, theres are two methods to do this
so im very confused what is the best method (efficiency, pythonic, elegant, none duplicated code) to do this:

lets say im have this class:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name
    
    def make_noise(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self,Dog):
            print(f"{self._name} make dog noise")
        if isinstance(self,Cat):
            print(f"{self._name} make cat noise")



class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(name)
    
class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(name)
```

or consider this method:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name
    
    def make_noise(self):
        pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(name)
    
    def make_noise(self):
        print(f"{self._name} make dog noise")

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(name)
    
    def make_noise(self):
        print(f"{self._name} make cat noise")
```

Comment: second way, also those `__init__` method definitions in child classes are redundant

Comment: The first way creates a circular dependency between the parent class and the child classes, and it also forces the parent class to do all of the work, which makes the child classes pointless.  Don't do it the first way.

Comment: If you do want to just put all the logic in one class, you can dispense with inheritance entirely; just have `Animal` take a `species` parameter (as a string or enum) and use that to implement the different `make_noise` conditions.

Comment: This 'problem' is the same in any OOP language, not just python. Choose the second way.

Comment: ok thx you very much, how you can reccomend me to do the __init__ for child classes? only if they have more own data members?

Comment: just don't do them at all, it is already defined in the parent class and you don't add anything new

Comment: The first way completely misses the point of `Cat` and `Dog` being subclass of `Animal` in the first place.